# Django migration failing because tables already exist?

Tags: django, postgresql

So I changed some models and the data structure changed dramatically and made a migration fail. I cleared out the tables that were affected in the database, deleted all the migration files and then tried to migrate again.

It made migrations for all the tables (even the ones that I left behind in the database) and when I try to migrate I get this error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: study
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying study.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 286, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "study_language" already exists
```

If I go into the migration files and delete the spots where it is trying to migrate an existing table, I get this error...

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: study
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying study.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 236, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 135, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 2003, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": []}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1994, in db_type
    rel_field = self.related_field
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1897, in related_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1631, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1618, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1603, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
ValueError: Related model u'study.Language' cannot be resolved
```

How can I get this to work without deleting all the tables I left behind in the db?

Comment: I am guessing when you first run migration there was some error and it stopped in between. So when you are running it now it is saying that table already exist. Try migrating it to the last migration before this and then migrate it again to this migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is that I commented out all of the migrations that were not in the db in models.py. I then cleaned the migration folder again and ran the command...

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate appname --fake-initial
```

Which went smoothly and then I uncommented the models I wanted to add to the db and ran a normal migration...

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Everything went smoothly